# boot Ubuntu 12.04 directly to a windows RDP session

Tags: 12.04, autostart, xrdp, remmina

Basically I want to auto start a windows RDP session. Turning my Ubuntu machine into a ThinClient so to speak. Purchasing thin-clients is out of the budget. I have Windows 2008 server r2 currently set up and running.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest open source:  http://remmina.sourceforge.net/

Install it.  Get the plug ins for RDP.  Set "SSH Tunneling" to unchecked in the advanced tab.  Put in the address information.

Then you can create a script to start it with one click: https://superuser.com/questions/628371/how-to-run-linux-remmina-from-the-terminal